# TYPO3: 'phpPath' for crawler extension setup in xampp

Tags: php, xampp, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x

I installed the extension "site crawler". The extension tells me that I need to specify the path to the PHP bin. So I wrote this little script to get the path:

```
<?php
    echo PHP_BINDIR;
```

I get `C:\PHP`. However if I enter this path into the extension settings, then i still get `No php binary found in 'C:\php'. Please update value for 'phpPath' in crawler extension setup.`

[image: no php]

Why do i still get this error message, and how can i solve this?

Comment: Probably, you should do exactly that - go into the settings for the extension "crawler" (in the extension manager) and set the correct path to your `php.exe` there. If you're using XAMPP, it's somewhere in the XAMPP directory, probably in a bin directory.

Comment: Wait, you are correct. I used the path `C:\xampp\php` before. Now if i use `C:/xampp/php/php.exe` then it is working! It would be so easy if they would add the message that i have to enter the path to the php.exe, instead of telling me that i have to enter the path to the php bin... THX for your help

Comment: The `php.exe` is the php binary - the `.exe` extension for binaries is non-standard for executable files.

Comment: Okay, and how should a normal user know this?

Answer (score 1):

Jost gave the answer, and black commented the missing info ...

that said, this is what works, go in the "Extensions" module to the Site Crawler and click the configuration icon (cogwheel). Scroll down to the variable `basic.phpPath` and substitute the default value with this *(in xampp the .exe file needs to be spelled out explicitly, its not in a bin)*:

```
C:/xampp/php/php.exe
```

Comment: Please add details to your answer. You just added the path to the php.exe and wrote "this works"

Comment: @Black any notion in particular ?